# Ranking matching in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL stored procedure that takes name and phone as input parameters and return ID as output parameter. I want to return ID if match on Name is found, but if not do matching on Phone. If I use OR statement, it returns two IDs but I just need to return only one id.

```
ID      Name        Phone
---------------------------
1       Dag         5070000000
2       Adam        2020000000
3       John        3010000000


@name ='Dag' 
@phone ='3010000000'
Select ID From Tbl Where Name=@name OR Phone=@phone
```

In this case, It returns both IDs of 1 and 3, but I want it to return only ID 1 since matching on name is more important that matching on phone for me. Please help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting one row, you can do:

```
select ID
from Tbl
where Name = @name OR Phone = @phone
order by (case when name = @name and phone = @phone then 1 
               when name = @name then 2
               else 3
          end)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note:  Not all databases recognize the ISO/ANSI standard `fetch first 1 row only`.  Some spell it `limit`.  Some `select top (1)`.